# Transpose the Json Using JQ : Filtering the inner List when using Map for the parent

Tags: json, select, jq

Hi I am trying to transpose the json from one format to another using the JQ.

My source JSON and JQ query is available at: https://jqplay.org/s/vt_4IbskaS

Issues with my query:

- I am not able to filter the Inner Array of Assets. (rendition == dog)
- I am not able to limit / remove the unwanted fields from the inner Array of Assets , i want only ID, Rendition and FileName..

My JQ Query::

```
{CompletedInstances,status , "AppMap": (.serviceResponse |  map( { (.appId): .assets } ) | add ) }
```

Expected response:

```
{
  "AppMap": {
    "testFile1234": {
      "assets": [
        {
          "filename": "testFile1234.scc",
          "rendition": "Dog",
          "assetId": 6565223
        },
        {
          "filename": "testFile1234-BG.wav",
          "rendition": "Dog",
          "assetId": 8234169
        },
        {
          "filename": "testFile1234-DK.wav",
          "rendition": "Dog",
          "assetId": 8234171
        }
      ]
    },
    "testFile4444": {
      "assets": [
        {
          "filename": "testFile1234.scc",
          "rendition": "Dog",
          "assetId": 8842169
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "CompletedInstances": 0,
  "status": "Completed"
}
```

Comment: Where are you *trying* to do either filter? I don't see any attempt at it in your code.

Comment: Also, please ensure that the question itself includes your input and actual output, not just desired output. Otherwise, it'll stop being helpful to others if the jqplay link ever breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the expected output:

```
{"AppMap": (.serviceResponse 
            | map({ (.appId): ({"assets": (.assets | (map(select(.rendition=="Dog"))
                               | map({filename, rendition, assetId}) ))})}) | add),
 CompletedInstances, status}
```

Comment: The output from your filter is missing the "assets" key that is expected.  Also, I think you'll find that using the `pipe` as the first rather than last element of a line is easier on the eye and can serve as a helpful guide to program logic.

Comment: @peak, thanks for noticing that. Although I have updated my answer, I feel there can be a better solution.